# How can I determine why ControlTransfer method of LibUsbDotNet in C# returns false?

Tags: c#, usb, libusbdotnet

I am trying to use the [ControlTransfer](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/a48945ae-2fb2-6925-49c5-08f7307cca94.htm) method of the [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html) C# library to communicate with a USB device but the method keeps returning false. My code is as follows:

```
private bool writeCtrlMsg(int value, int index, byte[] buffer)
{
    if (buffer == null || buffer.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Null or invalid length param.", "buffer");
    if (_rtlUSBDongle == null)
        throw new DongleNotOpeningException();
    if (!_rtlUSBDongle.IsOpen && !_rtlUSBDongle.Open())
        throw new DongleConnectionException();

    var shortVal = (short)value;
    var shortIndex = (short)index;

    var usbSetupPacket = new UsbSetupPacket(
        (byte)(UsbCtrlFlags.Direction_Out | UsbCtrlFlags.RequestType_Vendor | UsbCtrlFlags.Recipient_Device),
        0,
        value,
        index,
        buffer.Length
    );

    var result = _rtlUSBDongle.ControlTransfer(ref usbSetupPacket, buffer, buffer.Length, out var lengthTransferred);
    var errorCode = GetLastError();
    var errorCodeHex = errorCode.ToString("X");
    return result;
}
```

One example of a method call would be: `writeCtrlMsg(0x34, 0x619, new byte[] { 0x83 })`. No matter what values I use the `ControlTransfer` method keeps returning false. I couldn't find anything in the documentation about error handling or when this method returns false. I used the [`GetLastError`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getlasterror) call to see if I get any errors and it consistently returns 31 (or 0x1F), however I couldn't find anything online about this error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862740/controltransfer-instruction-not-sending-value-parameter-from-setup-packetr-in-li/8880641#8880641) is the only other question I was able to find on SO about this and the answer suggests to use 0x0 for the last parameter in the `UsbSetupPacket` constructor call. Tried, still returns false.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the following two:

[LastErrorNumber](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/e68c72d4-311e-4382-e99e-1d9db28ff9f0.htm)

```
UsbDevice.LastErrorNumber
```

> Returns the last error number reported by LibUsbDotNet.

And

[LastErrorString](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/f3942add-f073-3881-7146-0673415cee3b.htm)

```
UsbDevice.LastErrorString
```

> http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/f3942add-f073-3881-7146-0673415cee3b.htm

Comment: Well, I actually did find that method but when I tried using it was undefined. After looking more closely I noticed that it's defined as ```public **static** int LastErrorNumber```. Please update the cals to ```UsbDevice.LastErrorNumber``` and ```UsbDevice.LastErrorString```.

Comment: Good to know it helped. Updated as mentioned.

Comment: Yup, it helped, wouldn't have given it a second thought otherwise. Thanks!